# Save macro enabled workbook in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I want to save an XL sheet in macro enabled workbook into a SharePoint folder.

I have tried couple of things but it is giving me an error.

```
    Path = "https://xxxx/sites/xxxxx/"
    FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & ".xlsx", _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
```

I tried using the `FileFormat:=52`. The file is only saving in ".xslx" format.

Comment: Looks like it should be `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (which is 52) but your file extension is still set to `.xlsx` in your code, which should be `.xlsm`

Comment: Oh yes, now it is working. Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate your support:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file format should be `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (which is 52)

But your file extension is still set to `.xlsx` in your code, which should be `.xlsm` - The extension has to match the file format.

[List of File Formats for XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)